# How to Change Picture for Slick2D game in the taskbar

Tags: java, lwjgl, slick2d

I using `Slick2D` and `LWJGL` and i want to ask one question how to change game icon in the `taskbar` when i run it.

Comment: Fixed i just created `res` folder in `src` folder

Answer (score 0):

Actually depending on what you precisely want to do it can be quite hard.

The easyest way is to use Slick2d method: In GameContainer you can use the setIcon(String) method.

But on one of my personal project I had some difficulties loading images with Slick at start. So I looked for another solution with LWJGL :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    AppGameContainer app;
    try {

        app = new AppGameContainer(new Main("Anode"));
        org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.setIcon(loadIcon("resources/images/logo.png", app));
}

public static ByteBuffer[] loadIcon(String filepath,AppGameContainer app)
{
    BufferedImage image = null;
    try
    {
        image = ImageIO.read(app.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(filepath));
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    ByteBuffer[] buffers = new ByteBuffer[3];
    buffers[0] = loadIconInstance(image, 128);
    buffers[1] = loadIconInstance(image, 32);
    buffers[2] = loadIconInstance(image, 16);
    return buffers;
}

private static ByteBuffer loadIconInstance(BufferedImage image, int dimension)
{
    BufferedImage scaledIcon = new BufferedImage(dimension, dimension, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    Graphics2D g = scaledIcon.createGraphics();
    double ratio = 1;
    if(image.getWidth() > scaledIcon.getWidth())
    {
        ratio = (double) (scaledIcon.getWidth()) / image.getWidth();
    }
    else
    {
        ratio = (int) (scaledIcon.getWidth() / image.getWidth());
    }
    if(image.getHeight() > scaledIcon.getHeight())
    {
        double r2 = (double) (scaledIcon.getHeight()) / image.getHeight();
        if(r2 < ratio)
        {
            ratio = r2;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        double r2 =  (int) (scaledIcon.getHeight() / image.getHeight());
        if(r2 < ratio)
        {
            ratio = r2;
        }
    }
    double width = image.getWidth() * ratio;
    double height = image.getHeight() * ratio;
    g.drawImage(image, (int) ((scaledIcon.getWidth() - width) / 2), (int) ((scaledIcon.getHeight() - height) / 2),
            (int) (width), (int) (height), null);
    g.dispose();

    byte[] imageBuffer = new byte[dimension*dimension*4];
    int counter = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < dimension; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < dimension; j++)
        {
            int colorSpace = scaledIcon.getRGB(j, i);
            imageBuffer[counter + 0] =(byte)((colorSpace << 8) >> 24 );
            imageBuffer[counter + 1] =(byte)((colorSpace << 16) >> 24 );
            imageBuffer[counter + 2] =(byte)((colorSpace << 24) >> 24 );
            imageBuffer[counter + 3] =(byte)(colorSpace >> 24 );
            counter += 4;
        }
    }
    return ByteBuffer.wrap(imageBuffer);
}
```

I really advice you to use the Slick2d solution and is you don't reach your goal then you can switch to the more complicated one

Comment: i getting 2 errors
`Description Resource Path Location Type
The method setIcon(java.nio.ByteBuffer[]) in the type Display is not applicable for the arguments (com.sun.corba.se.impl.ior.ByteBuffer[]) Main.java /CobaltPlanet/src/lt/CobaltPlanet/nelixus line 102 Java Problem`
and
`Description Resource Path Location Type
The method wrap(byte[]) is undefined for the type ByteBuffer Main.java /CobaltPlanet/src/lt/CobaltPlanet/nelixus line 178 Java Problem`

Comment: Be careful with the import. it's import `java.nio.ByteBuffer` and you imported  `com.sun.corba.se.impl.ior.ByteBuffer`.

Comment: i geting crash `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: input == null!
 at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(Unknown Source)
 at lt.CobaltPlanet.nelixus.Main.loadIcon(Main.java:113)
 at lt.CobaltPlanet.nelixus.Main.main(Main.java:102)
`

Comment: Can you provide an example  by editing your question. The error comes from an argument that is not valid. Probably : `input == null`. Look for a solution this and provide your code if you don't find.

Comment: i don't have any `input == null` in my main class i only have `BufferedImage image = null;`

Comment: The problem is that your input is null. Maybe, it fails to reach your image. Have you tried debug to see how `loadIcon` works?

Comment: i geting this [foto](http://www.part.lt/img/240357a612a8141eda9da4eacc8e75ce313.png)

Comment: Actually It does not provide any clue as I don't see where is your breakpoint

Comment: This means that it did not succeed to reach your image in your resources. Be sure that `res` is in the `src` directory. And then test every path.

Comment: its reach becouse i use same photo in the another place

Comment: Is it in your classpath or  outside? Accessing resources with `getResources` require the resource to be in classpath